# Как переносить команды в другую консоль?

Tags: python, python-2.x

У меня есть две консоли, в первой я запускаю скрипт, а во второй должно идти выполнение сценария, как это можно реализовать? К примеру в сценарии:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('ipconfig')
```

Запускаю это в одной консоле, а в другой выполняется команда ipconfig

Comment: запускаете во второй консоли сервер которые запускает команды которые к нему пришли. В 1 вместо `subprocess.call` вызов сервера. Питон позволяет это дело примерно за 75 строк реализовать

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во 2 консоли запускаете сервер:

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing.managers


class MServer(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager):
    pass


MServer.register('ext_call', callable=subprocess.call)
mserver = MServer(address=('', 50000), authkey='abc')
server = mserver.get_server()
server.serve_forever()
```

В 1 инициализируете клиент:

```
import multiprocessing.managers


class MServer(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager):
    pass

MServer.register('ext_call')
mserver = MServer(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey='abc')
mserver.connect()
```

И юзаете его:

```
mserver.ext_call('echo 1', shell=True)
```

Comment: Ошибку бьет при подключение клиента

Comment: @AlexFirsov как насчет того чтобы использовать общепринятые практики описования ошибок?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 9, in <module>
    mserver.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 500, in connect
    conn = Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 169, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 308, in SocketClien
t
    s.connect(address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10049]

Comment: @AlexFirsov Поправил вроде...

Comment: Спасибо) Все работает теперь. Еще спросить хочу, почему в linux когда запускаю сервер вместо курсора появляться перекрестие какое-то + тыкать никуда не могу, скриншот как понял выделяет.

Comment: @AlexFirsov Ну, не знаю, у меня такого поведения нет. Скорее всего баг терминала... Попробуйте прокинуть вывод сервера через cat например. Хотя не уверен что поможет